# How long is the "defined grace period" for the idle scheduling class of the CFQ io scheduler?

Tags: linux, storage, performance-tuning, ionice

The `ionice` man page says

> A program running with idle io priority will only get disk  time
>   when no other program has asked for disk io for a defined grace period.

Where is this "grace period" defined?  Is it visable/tunable (perhaps via /sys)?

Comment: What are you trying to do? OS and distribution version, please?

Comment: linux (any distribution with the CFQ io scheduler).

Comment: I tend not to use the CFQ scheduler if I care about application performance. `deadline` or `noop` make more sense in many situations... Using either of those renders `ionice` unusable. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what the grace period is so that I can figure out if it makes sense for the load that I'm putting on a box.

Answer (score 4):

The grace period is 250 milliseconds.

http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0412.2/1099.html

```
There is an idle scheduling class, which only runs when nothing else
is using the disk. A grace period is defined for which idle has to
wait before getting disk access when other io has run. This defaults
to 250ms currently.
```

You didn't provide the OS version or distribution (and yes, it does make a difference), but the tunable for RHEL/CentOS 5+6 is [defined here](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/ch06s04.html) as *fifo_expire_async* in `/sys/block/[device]/queue/iosched/` (where [device] is sda, sdb, cciss0, etc.).

Comment: If I'm understanding that RH page correctly, is it not actually _slice_idle_ (and thus 8 ms)?

Comment: The more I play around with this, the more I'm convincing myself that the grace period is zero.  I'm on FC7 and I've tried writing some I/O intensive processes and assigning them to different scheduling classes .  No matter how much I saturate the cfq-scheduled block device, I never see any blocking on the "idle" processes.  I think maybe it's time for me to ask a more general question of "how do you test that ionice is actually working".

Comment: I'm not sure. As I stated earlier, you may want to look at one of the other scheduler algorithms. I prefer `deadline` over `cfq`.

Comment: The more general question is over at http://serverfault.com/q/369382/95287